# weird ~infinite loop with $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing loop polling, to wait for events, and I'm having some trouble with an infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.factory('UserEvents', function ($http) {

    var manageEvent = function (event) {

        //do some work here

        //and then, poll:
        window.setTimeout(poll, 0);
    }

    var poll = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/get-events',
        })
        .success(function(event, status) {
            manageEvent(event)
        });
    }

    service = {
        poll: poll,
    }

    return service
});

function mainController($scope, UserEvents) {

    UserEvents.poll();

}
```

Once the first event is received the success method of $http.get is executed without any request being done, which creates the loop. At some point it magically stops, sending its GET request.
It's like if the function 'poll' was using the previous $http.get promise, already resolved (???)

If I set a timeout of 200ms in the 'manageEvent' function, the problem doesn't appear, but it's not a clean solution to me.

Can someone explain to me what's happening here ?

Thanks

Comment: `At some point it magically stops, sending its GET request.` - what is in response? Maybe server declines your repeated connections, try to log response status in `.error(response, status)`.

Comment: The server is tornado, and I logged the requests on its side: none is sent to it... And nothing is catched in .error :/

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to sniff your traffic, or even network monitoring in development tools?